# AWS Crawler Error: User does not have access to target s3://gurpreet-cross-account-bucket/

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-policies, aws-roles

I am getting below error while running AWS crawler, I have assigned proper IAM roles, trust account access permission

> Crawler Error:
> User does not have access to target s3://gurpreet-cross-account-bucket/

Comment: Actually, I was trying to setup cross account AWS setup with IAM Role, Policies and user creation for real use case scenario to get data from S3 bucket which reside in another AWS account(say account A) and create AWS glue catalog in another AWS account(say account B) and then using Athena Sibma driver to view data in PowerBI tool